# OpenGL 2d texture not working

Tags: c++, opengl, png, 2d, textures

I'm working on a 2D game project, and I wanted to wrap the openGl texture in a simple class. The texture is read from a 128x128px .png (with alpha channel) using **libpng**. Since the amount of code is pretty large, I'm using pastebin.

The code files:

- Texture class: http://pastebin.com/gbGMEF2Z
- PngReader class: http://pastebin.com/h6uP5Uc8 (seems to work okay, so I removed the description).
- OpenGl code: http://pastebin.com/PVhwnDif

To avoid wasting your time, I will explain the code a little bit:

- *Texture class*: a wrapper for an OpenGL texture. The `loadData` function sets up the texture in gl (this is the function I suspect that doesn't work).
- *OpenGl code*: the `debugSetTexture` function puts a texture in the `temp` variable which is used in the `graphicsDraw()` function. This is because it is not in the same source file as `main()`. In the `graphicsMainLoop()` function, I use the `Fork()` function which in fact calls `fork()`, and stores the `pid` of the spawned process.

From `main()`, this is what I do:

```
Strategy::IO::PngReader reader ("/cygdrive/c/Users/Tibi/Desktop/128x128.png");
reader.read();
grahpicsInit2D(&argc, argv);
debugSetTexture(reader.generateTexture());
graphicsMainLoop();
reader.close();
```

I tried an application called gDEBugger, and in the texture viewer, there was a texture generated, but size was 0x0px.

I suspect that the problem happens when the texture is loaded using Texture::loadTexture().

Comment: Why do you use Cygwin? And do you run the program in the Cygwin environment?

Comment: "I suspect that the Texture::loadData() function doesn't work"... so did you try doing the exact same thing on the same data in a minimal example outside of the Texture class? Does that work?

Comment: @AndiDog It is the way Eclipse is configured... I don't have mingw installed, and I'm not sure libpng exists on windows.

Comment: @Bart I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to tell me. Please clarify.

Comment: Well then the first obvious thing to do is try and see if the file exists under that path, or whether it should be "C:\Users\..." instead (or why not use relative paths?). And libpng should be compilable with any compiler I assume, as it's so widespread.

Comment: It exists, that is not the problem. I use absolute path for debugging/testing only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check GL error codes after GL calls.

For example add this method to your class:

```
GLuint Texture::checkError(const char *context)
{
  GLuint err = glGetError();
  if (err > 0 )  { 
    std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << err << " glGetError() in " << context 
    << std::endl;
  }
  return err;
}
```

then call it like so:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, handle);
checkError("glBindTexture");
```

Assuming it succeeds in loading the png file, suppose your program fails in glBindTexture? (strong hint)

You did call your Error function for your file handling, but does your program halt then or chug on?

Here's a serious issue: Texture PngReader::generateTexture() returns Texture by value. This will cause your Texture object to be copied on return (handle and all) and then ~Texture() to be called, destroying the stack-based copy. So your program will call glDeleteTextures a couple times!

If you want to return it by value, you could wrap it in a shared_ptr<> which does reference counting. This would cause the destructor to be called only once:

```
#include <tr1/memory>
typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<Texture> TexturePtr;
```

Use TexturePtr as your return type. Initialize it in generateTexture() like this:

```
TexturePtr t(new Texture);
```

then change all the method access to go through -> instead of .

Comment: Forgot to mention that the Error function outputs to the log file if there is any error, that's all, and no error appears. I also tried to generate an image in memory (using memset), but it didn't work either. I'm trying the glGetError now.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem... the destructor was called, which was causing trouble.